# Jitterbit web service request failure

Tags: jitterbit

I'm using Jitterbit to call a web service and output the response to a txt file. My web service call is failing with an authentication error. I understand the error but don't understand why I'm getting it. The credentials are correctly configured in the web service method. So, my question is, is there a way to output the web service request to the operation log so that I can see what values are truly being passed?

Thanks, Jason

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using global variables for your credentials and using the built in function...

```
 WriteToOperationLog($variableName)
```